# Iterate through a text file in C++ using for_each and istream_iterator to find file names

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, istream-iterator

Working on a C++ HW project. We were given code to read all .dat files in a directory into a single .txt file, which we then need to extract values from, in no particular order. The code we were given was:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define listcmd "dir \b *.dat > datfiles.txt 2>nul"
#endif
```

This gives me a text file with a lot more information than just the .dat file names, though... volume information, directory paths, file data, etc.

We then do the following to read the file, but I do not understand how this works:

```
system(listcmd);
ifstream datfiles("datfiles.txt");
for_each(istream_iterator<string>(datfiles), istream_iterator<string>(), analyze);
datfiles.close();
```

I have been looking over the istream_iterator and for_each pages at cplusplus.com, but could use some clarification. What exactly is this for_each statement doing?

Am I correct in thinking that it is doing the following:

- reading one string at a time from the istream (stopping on white space)
- passing that string to the analyze function (to perform whatever processing... attempting to open the file in my case and reading in values)
- once control returns, continue doing this until end of file reached or stream fails

Answer (score 0):

After a weekend of frustration and going on a wild goose chase, the answer is simply that I should have used "/b" instead of "\b" in the following section:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define listcmd "dir \b *.dat > datfiles.txt 2>nul"
#endif
```

Once updated the text file is created properly with a very neat list of .dat files, one to each line.

Answer (score 0):

The function of `for_each` is:

> Applies function fn to each of the elements in the range [first,last).

The behavior of this template function is equivalent to:

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function fn)
{
    while (first!=last) {
       fn (*first);
       ++first;
    }
   return fn;      // or, since C++11: return move(fn);
 }
```